# Is there a way to pause mail delivery in Postfix (accumulate in queue)?

Tags: email-server, dovecot, postfix

When using combination of Postfix/Dovecot, is there a way to tell smtp server (Postfix) not to store mails on disk but hold/add them to queue until "maintenance finished"?

Useful for disk upgrades, volume extensions, chkdisk etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe so; the incoming queue is on disk. Perhaps you could temporarily move the queue to a ramdisk mount?

```
mkdir /mnt/pframqueue
mount -t tmpfs -o size=512M tmpfs /mnt/pframqueue
service postfix stop
mv /var/spool/postfix/* /mnt/pframqueue/
<<<adjust 'queue_directory' in main.cf to /mnt/pframqueue>>>
service postfix start
```

Do the opposite once you're done.

IMHO that's more trouble than it's worth, especially if something goes screwy in the mv

Answer (score 14):

Use this to stop (pause) and start delivery of outgoing mail again:

```
sudo postconf -e defer_transports=smtp; sudo postfix reload
sudo postconf -e defer_transports=; sudo postfix reload; sudo postfix flush
```

This should be applicable to other transports as well.

Source: [nixtips.net](https://www.nixtips.net/useful-postfix-one-liners/)

Answer (score 3):

Just shut down postfix. Any legit sending server will queue your mail and retry after a time delay  if it is not able to contact your server. As long as your maintenance is short, say under 6 hours, your chances of losing mail are very small.

Comment: This could be a good answer but then what to do with internal users who connect to the smtp for outgoing mail?

Comment: @Alex During maintenance?

Comment: @Alex - I agree with Michael here. If you only have a single server, you're clearly not in a high-availability environment to start with, so just take things down during a published maintenance period. This is fairly standard practice, and is typically well-received by users as long as you communicate with them about it.

Comment: The nasty corner case involves things like [ActionMailer](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) that need Postfix and send mail that isn't from local users. And really, why should a "forgot my password?" form have its own mail queue?